# Raycasting to make an enemy jump

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence

As stated above, I am trying to build a simple game, but I can't seem to get the enemies moving correctly. The game is a Minecraft style block-based game. The code I am using so far makes the enemy start following me when I get within a certain distance and stop following once I get a certain distance away.

The problem I am having with this script is that the enemy sort of floats off into the distance when I escape him. More importantly, I cannot for the life of me get the enemy to jump. I know that I should be using two Raycasts for this: one to detect a block in front which will make the enemy jump and another to detect below the enemy and let him fall to the level below if there is no collier at his feet? I have no idea how to go about implementing this and some help would be greatly appreciated.

The code I have thus far can be seen below:

```js
var target : Transform; //the enemy's target
var moveSpeed = 3; //move speed
var rotationSpeed = 3; //speed of turning
var range : float=10f;
var range2 : float=10f;
var stop : float=0;
var myTransform : Transform; //current transform data of this enemy

function Awake() {
    myTransform = transform; //cache transform data for easy access/preformance
}
  
function Start() {
    target = GameObject.FindWithTag("1Player").transform; //target the player
}
  
function Update () {
    //rotate to look at the player
    var distance = Vector3.Distance(myTransform.position, target.position);
    if (distance<=range2 &&  distance>=range) {
        myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTransform.rotation, 
                Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - myTransform.position),
                rotationSpeed*Time.deltaTime);
    } else if (distance <= range && distance > stop) {
        //move towards the player
        myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTransform.rotation, 
                Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - myTransform.position),
                rotationSpeed*Time.deltaTime);
        myTransform.position += myTransform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    } else if (distance <= stop) {
        myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTransform.rotation, 
                Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - myTransform.position),
                rotationSpeed*Time.deltaTime);
    }
     
    //lock rotation on x and y axis to zero
    myTransform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0f, myTransform.eulerAngles.y, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The design can change really a lot. It depends how clever AI do you want ? And how realistic it should be. Firstly you should check distance and as I saw you did that. The question is what if there is a wall or something ? Maybe they are so close to each other but there is a wall between them. This is why you need raycast. So you send a raycast from enemy to player. If there is no obstacle between them AI can decide that "aye I should come after you". But here is another problem for being realistic. What if its not looking to you ? If the AI can spot the player when it looks somewhere else, it is not that cool right ? So you also check if the player is in front of the AI. Maybe we can do it like this :

```
var heading = target.position - transform.position;
var dot: float = Vector3.Dot(heading, transform.forward);
```

so if dot is -1 we can say it is directly behind and +1 means in front of it. Well, now another problem. If player should be in front of the AI to be spotted then AI can not stand right ? It should move and turn around randomly. We can work on that later if you gonan need it.

Now another problem what if you hide after an object ? What it should do ? I mean when you are running if something came between you and AI, since raycast will fail it will stop following you right ? What we can do for it ? My sugesstion store the last position of the player which AI saw. And at least go to there to check if AI can find the player there. If it cant, it may keep moving randomly. By doing this it will looks more realistic I believe.

Edit: Lol I realised that i just improved you design and forgot to answer what exactly you asked.

Firstly AI shoudl know if it is grounded or not. What we need to know first distance to ground when we send raycast we gonan need it.

```
var distanceToGround = GetComponent<Collider>().bounds.extents.y;

function boolean isGrounded(){
   return Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector3.up, distanceToGround + 0, 1);
}
```

AI should send a raycast not from its head more like below the knees. Not send it too far away just a little distance will be enough. It is just to understand it there is an obstacle. And also send another raycast but this time now below the knees. From the jump height. And if it dont hit anything we can decide that there is an obstacle (first raycast says that) but AI can jump over it (second raycast says that). After deciding it, if AI also grounded that means it can jump and pass trough the obstacle.

Lets say this is the part 1. If you want me to keep telling, I can write another part for you. Have a nice day !

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed reply but I am still unsure of what it is I need to be doing should I add this code beneath my already completed code or should I be replacing something in my current code? I would love for you to help me complete this script.

Comment: Well if you want to do what I explained probably you should start again with new script. Sadly I dont have time to write and try a script on Unity but my instructions are clear to follow. Isn't it ? You can try to make a function for everything I said such as isGrounded , isPlayerInMySight , etc.